# Convert any arbitrary character to a subscript in a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, jupyter-notebook

EDIT:

My main problem- which I did not explain initially (sorry)- is that I don't know ahead of time what I am going to be printing. I am doing a set of calculations which at the end require exporting a printable report. The report might have any of a number of arbitrary subscript characters, and it might not.

I initially started to try using `str.replace()` combined with a simple `dict` (inspired by `str.maketrans()`) to convert certain character sequences to another form, and ran into a roadblock when I could not find a unicode subscript for `g`.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I am looking for a unicode version of the *subscript* letter "g". According to [this file](http://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) at the Unicode Consortium, it looks like it doesn't exist (when search for `<sub>` in the character list).

If I am correct and this character isn't available, is there an easy way to create it in a Jupyter notebook? Or do I have to resort to this (which, imo, doesn't qualify as "easy"):

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML(f'Ground snow load (P<sub>g</sub>) = {Pg}'))
```

BONUS: Is there a better more generalized way of finding oft-used scientific characters (including superscripts and subscripts, but also things like the degree symbol)? One nice feature of Jupyter notebook that I'm already aware of is creating Greek characters by key sequences such as `\gamma<tab>` for `γ`. It would be nice to have something similar for superscripts and subscripts. I could use LATEX markdown and then copy and paste, but that's hardly convenient.

Comment: What do you mean by "unicode version of the letter "g""? That *is* the Unicode version of the letter "g". Are you looking for a character that represents a subscript g?

Comment: Yes, sorry, bad wording.

Comment: If you're on markdown mode, you could use `$_g$`

Comment: I think Jupyter notebooks have some sort of LaTeX support you should use.

Comment: @Mephy That is handy, however, I do not necessarily know what the character will be ahead of time. My original idea was to use `str.maketrans()` to create `dict` for translating `g` to `_g`, but then I could not find `_g` in the unicode list. I'll clarify this in teh question.

Comment: @user2357112 The LATEX support is nice, but I haven't been able to figure a way to make it dynamic. I don't know the character ahead of time.